# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Translation error

Tags: websphere, translation, axis

I get the followwing exception when trying to read a SOAP response from a reply queue on IBM WAS 8.5:

```
Caught an AxisFault while executing the web service call [org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Translation error]
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Translation error
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:512)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
```

I could not find anything related to this error by googling or on IBM's websites.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that Utils code in open source, "Translation error" is probably the message being sent back in a SOAPFault from the remote web service.  Why the remote service is sending back a SOAPFault isn't apparent.  If you turn on trace of org.apache.*=all:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all you'll be able to see the incoming message in the trace and that might give you more information.

Comment: Since we are using JMS for sending soap messages, i was able to enable debug using "*=info: Messaging=all: com.ibm.mq.*=all"

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199176

this helped to figure/see that our SOAP content was getting truncated
<Remaining characters truncated>

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve this by un-cheking the option at
Queues > "Your Queue" > Advanced properties

[]Append RFH version 2 headers to messages sent to this destination